# Callback in batch Request in Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I do one batch Request and in this batch Request there are 2 Requests (there is dependecies between 2 Request). Then, I have 3 callback but the callback relative to the batch seem dont give information about  possible errors of two Request (and this will be very useful because I can handle only one error and no the two error relative of two callback of two Request).

The Facebook documentation tell:
*Batching allows you to pass instructions for several operations in a single HTTP request. You can also specify dependencies between related operations (described in a section below). Facebook will process each of your independent operations in parallel and will process your dependent operations sequentially. Once all operations have been completed, a consolidated response will be passed back to you and the HTTP connection will be closed.*

*Its possible that one of your requested operations may throw an error. This could be because, for example, you don't have permission to perform the requested operation. In this scenario, the batch API throws a similar response to the standard Graph API, but encapsulated in the batch response syntax:*

```
curl \
     -F 'access_token=...'\
     -F 'batch=[{ "method":"POST","relative_url":"me/feed","body":"message=Test update"}]' \
https://graph.facebook.com
```

And, in my opinion, it is not clear if it is possible or not recover the error/s from message.

This is my code with callbacks:

```
 Request.Callback reqPublishCallback= new Request.Callback() {
 @Override
 public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            if(response.getError() == null) {
               Log.w(LOG_TAG, "reqPublishCallback: "+ "OK");
               actionCreatedTextView.setText("OK action");

               //                   Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_CREATED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
               Log.e(LOG_TAG, "reqPublishCallback: "+ response.getError().toString());
               Log.d(LOG_TAG, response.getError().getCategory().toString());
               actionCreatedTextView.setText(response.getError().getCategory().toString());
            }

         }


      };

      RequestBatch.Callback batchCallback= new RequestBatch.Callback() {

         @Override
         public void onBatchCompleted(RequestBatch batch) {
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Batch completed: "+ "OK");
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, batch + "");

            //
         }
      };
```

**Is possible handle all errors from batch callback ? (batchCallback) in the code**

Comment: There's no direct way to handle errors from a batch callback, this is by design. It's merely to inform you that the batch has completed. Ideally, you should handle errors locally (to each request), but if you wanted, you could set some global (or class-level) state about the errors in the individual callbacks, and then look for them in the batch callback, since it's guaranteed to be called last.